# Music Player that allows searching id3-tag field "comment"

Tags: music-player, search, id3-tag

I am using the id3-tag "comment" field to assign tags that characterize the content of songs to mp3 of my music library. The contents of a comment field of an mp3 file could look like this:

```
upBeat happy fast bassHeavy
```

In this example I want to be able to search my library for 'upBeat' and have all songs listed that contain this string in their comment field.

I have a DJ-Software on my laptop that supports this. I want to be able to do the same thing on my Android device. I tried it with shuttle, Poweramp, doubleTwist and phonograph so far. To me it looks like none of them are capable of achieving this.

Are there any players that support this?

If not, is there a different (better?) way of finding all songs belonging to one tag? Moving the same file to a different device (e.g. desktop computer) should not require reassigning the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Pulsar Music Player will allow you to edit the comment field. The search function will search ***all*** fields including the comment field but I found no way to search in ***only*** the comment fields. Here's the link:

[Pulsar Music Player Pro - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.pulsar.pro)

Comment: So, I tried Pulsar Player. Maybe I'm just too blind to find it, but:
1) Search function doesn't include the comment tag, I can't find an option to customize that,
2) I can't even find the functionality to add a (smart) playlist from within Pulsar Player

Comment: Pulsar does not support full id3 tag search!

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited ability of Android media players to search the "comment" a likely workaround will be using a different field as a search target as suggested [here](https://traktortips.com/2012/11/27/organizing-music-files-in-traktor/):

In this scenario, pick a lesser useful field such as **Album**

- Decide which tags to use e.g *upBeat* *happy* *fast* *bassHeavy*
- A good sarting point in doing a batch "clean-up". You can use [mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) (freeware) on desktop to trim down the information to a minimum.
- remove everything apart from *name*, *artist*, *genre*, *bitrate* and *date* added. That includes deleting the **album information** (see below for reasons).
- (Add some information for each tune to the album field instead of “comments” field that now has your key information. Assuming you already set this up, just proceed)
- Copy the **comments field** above to the **album** field. This is the reason of ealier deletion of  the original entries at the start,

  (Now if you  don’t care what album a track has come from but  care what key and mood it has as original author - your Android player has a big album of key tunes of every mood, energy, bpm and genre)
- You can easily do a quick search to find music belonging to a certain tag with most Android music players available.

**Acknowledgements**

- (Original author Alan) [Organizing Music Files & id3 tags in Traktor](https://traktortips.com/2012/11/27/organizing-music-files-in-traktor/)